# How to iterate through a list in JSP using Spring framework

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

So, I have a list that I passed it through the model from my Spring controller to JSP. How do I iterate through the list inside the JSP?

Assume, the list has several hyperlinks that I would like to display in JSP. How to do this without scriptlets?

Comment: Depends how you're returning it, if it's returning an array of JSON objects or if it's directly use a for loop in the JSP.

Comment: I should iterate in JSP itself!

Comment: Yeah but you could write say a jQuery loop in a jsp file, you mention you're using a Spring controller so you may be just using it to query JSON.  @Chirag Kathiriya has the right answer if it's just directly through the JSP.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can use jstl tag and display the list

```
<c:forEach var="listVar" items="${listName}"> //add the model attribute of list in items
    <option value ="10"><c:out value="${listVar.attribute}"/></option>
</c:forEach>
```